# How to use Object Array Returned from BeanClass and Display in DropDown in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jsf, dropdown, javabeans

I have two arrays returned from BeanClass (eventBean):
SelectItem[] abc;
Object[] xyz;

When i use SelectItem Array, i get list of Values in MultiSelect Box (Expected)

```
<h:selectManyListbox size="5" styleClass="selectListBox">    
      <f:selectItems value='#{eventBean.abc}' />
  </h:selectManyListbox>
```

But, when i use Object Array, i get Internal Server Error 500 in my JSP (Error)

```
<h:selectManyListbox size="5" styleClass="selectListBox">
         <f:selectItems value='#{eventBean.xyz}' />
```

</h:selectManyListbox>

How can we use Object Array Data with SelectItems Value Tag?

Answer (score 0):

If the member elements of your selection component are not instances of `SelectItem`, additional `var` and item attributes must be used to correctly identify the select item object's value, label, etc.

```html
<h:selectManyListbox size="5" styleClass="selectListBox">
    <f:selectItems value="#{eventBean.xyz}" var="obj" itemLabel="#{obj.name}" itemValue="#{obj}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Just replace `name` with your custom object's display property, or use it's `toString()` implementation.